# apply react.gradle throw error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

when I'm use following line inside **app/build.gradle** it throw error

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Error:-
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/.../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  Cannot add task ':app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets' as a task with that name already exists.

> inside react.gradle line 58 is

```
def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Could you show us your `build.gradle` file please?

Comment: thanks @Dan issue resolved. its happen because on top i applied **react.gradle** file and middle of **build.gradle** file it already exist i'm uncommented it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```